# Smartface App Studio 4.4.0.5 IDE Bug

Tags: smartface.io

I get this bug when launching the studio: 
"Control 'dckActionsEditor' has no parent window." and afterwards can't do anything as IDE just keeps dropping this bug out non-stop. Im using windows 7 SP1 ,any ideas what to do ?

Answer (score 0):

When your Smartface ide is open, under the "View" tab you can see "Reset Panels" as in the screenshot below.
Press this, and after that close your ide and open it again.

[image]

Most probably this will solve your problem.